# Using valijson with Nlohmann's JSON for Modern C++ to validate schemas with subschemas

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

Can valijson be made to work with Nlohmann's json parser for schemas read from a file with references to subschemas in other files?

```
json mySchemaDoc;
if (!valijson::utils::loadDocument("testSchema.json", mySchemaDoc)) {
    cout << "failed to create schema";
}

Schema mySchema;
SchemaParser parser;
NlohmannJsonAdapter mySchemaAdapter(mySchemaDoc);
parser.populateSchema(mySchemaAdapter, mySchema);
```

I'm getting a std::runtime_error on this last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the problem was related to forward vs backward slashes (Unix vs Windows)...